# naive filtering using fft in python

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, lowpass-filter

I'm trying to write *naiv low pass filter* using Python. 
Values of the *Fourier Transformant* higher than a specific frequency should be equal to 0, right? 
As far as I know that should to work.

But after an inverse fourier transformation what I get is just noise.

**Program1** records *RECORD_SECONDS* from microphone and writes information about `fft` in `fft.bin` file.

**Program2** reads from this file, do `ifft` and plays result on speakers.

In addition, I figured out, that **every**, even very little change in `fft` causes Program2 to fail.

Where do I make mistake?

**Program1:**

```
import pickle
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1 #1-mono, 2-stereo
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 2

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

f = open("fft.bin", "wb")

Tsamp = 1./RATE
#arguments for a fft
fft_x_arg = np.fft.rfftfreq(CHUNK/2, Tsamp)
#max freq
Fmax = 4000


print("* recording")

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):

    #read one chunk from mic
    SigString = stream.read(CHUNK)

    #convert string to int
    SigInt = np.fromstring(SigString, 'int')

    #calculate fft
    fft_Sig = np.fft.rfft(SigInt)
    """
    #apply low pass filter, maximum freq = Fmax
    j=0
    for value in fft_x_arg:
        if value > Fmax:
            fft_Sig[j] = 0
        j=j+1
    """

    #write one chunk of data to file
    pickle.dump(fft_Sig,f)

print("* done recording")


f.close()

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

**Program2:**

```
import pyaudio
import pickle
import numpy as np

CHUNK = 1024


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=44100/2,   #anyway, why 44100 Hz plays twice faster than normal?
                output=True)

f = open("fft.bin", "rb")

#load first value from file
fft_Sig = pickle.load(f)
#calculate ifft and cast do int
SigInt = np.int16(np.fft.irfft(fft_Sig))
#convert once more - to string
SigString = np.ndarray.tostring(SigInt)

while SigString != '':
    #play sound
    stream.write(SigString)
    fft_Sig = pickle.load(f)
    SigInt = np.int16(np.fft.irfft(fft_Sig))
    SigString = np.ndarray.tostring(SigInt)

f.close()

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

FFTs operate on complex numbers. You might be able to feed them real numbers (which will get converted to complex by setting the imaginary part to 0) but their outputs will always be complex.

This is probably throwing off your sample counting by 2 among other things. It should also be trashing your output because you're not converting back to real data.

Also, you forgot to apply a 1/N scale factor to the IFFT output. And you need to keep in mind that the frequency range of an FFT is half negative, that is it's approximately the range -1/(2T) <= f < 1/(2T). BTW, 1/(2T) is known as the [Nyquist frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), and for real input data, the negative half of the FFT output will mirror the positive half (i.e. for y(f) = F{x(t)} (where F{} is the forward [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)) y(f) == y(-f).

I think you need to read up a bit more on DSP algorithms using FFTs. What you're trying to do is called a [brick wall filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_filter#Brick-wall_filters).

Also, something that will help you a lot is [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/),  which will help you see what the data looks like at intermediate steps. You need to look at this intermediate data to find out where things are going wrong.